# how to group homogeneous properties in a python class

Tags: python-3.x

using Python I'm creating a class with some properties that can be divided in homogeneous groups.
In some other languages (like C) I liked to use structures to group fields belonging to the same "topic", to maintain the code clean.

For example, let's say that I would like to group all the field related to the configurations of my program like: *filepath*, *username*, *version*, etc... under the *config* properties.

Folks, What do you do/use to manage this kind of data?

here an extract of the class what I wrote but doesn't work, because it is not supported.

```
...
...
self.config.filepath = ''
self.config.username = ''
self.config.version = ''
...
...
```

What is the more elegant way, or the best practice, to face to this situation?

Many thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways:

Using a `dict`:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = {}
        self.config['filepath'] = ''
        self.config['username'] = ''
        self.config['version']= ''
```

Using `argparse.Namespace`:

```
from argparse import Namespace

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = Namespace(filepath='', username='', version='')
```

Using `types.SimpleNamespace`:

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = SimpleNamespace(filepath='', username='', version='')
```

Comment: thanks for your message.
I created a data structure using SimpleNamespace, it works well for different "levels" like this:

    self.config = SimpleNamespace(struct_1 = '')
    self.config.struct_1 = SimpleNamespace(substruct_11 = 'abc1')

To use of these "structure" I need to be able to perform some actions like:

 - get the number of elements for that level

 - get the value of the element using an index

I suppose that it is more simple to be achieved through the dictionaries, however with this I wasn't able to make a "dictionary of dictionary"
How should I proceed?thanks!